# ps columns auto width

Tags: list, awk, process, ps

`ps -eo user,pid,pcpu,pmem,vsz,rss,tty,stat,start,time,group,args | awk 'match($0, /some[0-9]/)'` -
When I run this command on my Debian server, the output of the "group" column will be stripped due to not enough space.
Man ps: "egroup      EGROUP    effective group ID of the process.  This will be the textual group ID, if it can be obtained and the field width permits, or a decimal representation otherwise.
                             (alias group)."
I have tried:

```
ps -eo user,pid,pcpu,pmem,vsz,rss,tty,stat,start,time,group,args | awk 'match($0, /some[0-9]/)'

ps -wwo user,pid,pcpu,pmem,vsz,rss,tty,stat,start,time,group,args | awk 'match($0, /some[0-9]/)'

ps --width 90000000 -eo user,pid,pcpu,pmem,vsz,rss,tty,stat,start,time,group,args | awk 'match($0, /some[0-9]/)'

ps -wweo user,pid,pcpu,pmem,vsz,rss,tty,stat,start,time,group,args | awk 'match($0, /some[0-9]/)' | cat
```

But still, the group column is converted to decimals instead of group name.

So my question is: How can I tell ps to always show me full columns.

Note: this command is running thru php exec().

Thank you.

Comment: @hek2mgl which one worked for you?

Comment: I admit that I only tried the first

Comment: @hek2mgl I have a long args result. That's the difference, I guess.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem was solved by adding a width to a column itself:

```
ps -eo user,pid,pcpu,pmem,vsz,rss,tty,stat,start,time,group:50,args | awk 'match($0, /some[0-9]/)'
```

Where 50 from "`group:50`" is the width of the column.

Comment: I also was about to suggest this, however I couldn't reproduce the problem.